# How to create a ribbon with shadows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shadows

I have seen lots of images like this which used a slight shadow very nicely as if the sides are folded into each other but I don't know how to create such thing. I'm not looking for a full tutorial. Just a few tips would be fine. How do you go about making something like this?

[image: triangle]

Comment: Please se the duplicate link above your question. If that fails to answer your question, feel free to click the "flag" link and ask a moderator to reopen, explaining why the duplicate is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw one of the above strips and do a blend from the edge in, a grayish version of the color blending into the color. Copy/rotate until you form all three sides.